# Converting arrays of one type to another

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, casting

Basically I have an array of doubles. I want to pass this array to a function (ProcessData) which will treat them as short ints. Is creating a short pointer and pointing it to the array, then passing this pointer to the function ok (code 1) ?

Is this in effect the same as creating a short array, iterating through each element and converting each element of the double array to a short and then passing the short array pointer (code 2) ? Thanks

```
//code 1
//.....
short* shortPtr = (short*)doubleArr;
ProcessData(shortPtr);
```

..

```
//code 2
//...
short shortArr [ARRSIZE];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++)
{
    shortArr[i] = (short)doubleArr[i];
}
ProcessData(shortArr);
```

Comment: No, it's not ok. It's not the same thing.

Comment: It is like saying "Here's a sequence of doubles, but pretend it is a sequence of  short ints instead. And good luck with that."

Comment: If a `double` takes 8 bytes and a `short` takes 2 bytes, you will be slicing each `double` into 4 irrelevant parts.

Comment: Also, please pick **one** language C or C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This question is applicable for both C and C++. We also use arrays plain arrays in C++.

Comment: @Engineer999 Many languages have plain arrays, that does not make them the same.

Comment: So my code is not C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that. Here's at least one reason why:

An array is a contiguous sequence of several memory allocations accessed by way of an index, like so

```
[----][----][----]
```

Note the four dashes inside the square brackets. That is to indicate that in most situations in C/C++, an `int` is *four bytes long*. Arrays cells can be accessed by their index because if we know the memory address of the first cell (`m`) and we know how big each cell is meant to be (`c`) - in this case, four bytes, we can easily find the memory location of any index by doing `m + index * c`

```
[----][----][----]
^ array[0]


[----][----][----]
 ----  ----  ^ array[2]
```

Fundamentally, this is why pointers can be treated like arrays in C/C++, because when you are accessing arrays, you are basically doing pointer arithmetic anyway.

In most cases in C/C++, a short is *2 bytes long*, so to represent it in the same way

```
[--][--][--]
```

If you create a `short` pointer, and try to use it as an array, it is expected to point to something which is arranged like the above. If you try to index it, it is going to have problems: if you were dealing with an array of shorts, the location of array[2] is the same as `m + 2 * index`, as shown below

```
[--][--][--]
 --  --  ^ array[2] (note moving along four bytes)
```

But since we are in reality dealing with an array of integers, the following will happen

```
[----][----][----]
 ----  ^ array[2] (again moving along four bytes)
```

Which is clearly wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can't just cast, as the various comments have said. But if you use iterators you can get more or less the same effect:

```
void do_something_with_short(short i) {
    /* whatever */
}

template <class Iter>
void do_something(Iter first, Iter last) {
    while (first != last)
        do_something_with_short(*first++);
}
```

You can call that template function with iterators into an array of any arithmetic type (in fact, any type that's implicitly convertible to `short` or, if you add a cast at the point of the call to `do_something_with_short`, with a type that requires a cast):

```
double data[10]; // needs to be initialized, of course
do_something(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because `++ptr` actually does something like `ptr = (char*)ptr + sizeof *ptr` (with `sizeof (char)` being 1 by definition). So incrementing a `double` pointer moves it by (usually) 8 bytes, while incrementing a `short` pointer moves it by only 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your kids study piano and occasionally ask you to scan for them a stack of [sheet music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_music) given to them by their teacher who was born in the 20th century (just like yourself). You take those sheets to your office and feed them to the photocopier. It creates decent digital scans that your kids can use on their piano equipped with a touch screen. All goes well until one day the child brings to you an old rare set of [vinyl records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramophone_record). She's desperate of finding those melodies in sheet music form but asks you to at least copy the records. Inexperienced in musical matters, you take those disks to your office, load them in the [automatic document feeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_document_feeder) of the scanner and realize that you are deep in ... um... crap only as you hear the sounds of the vinyl disks breaking inside the stupid machine. Even if the photocopier were not equipped with an ADF, and you had to place all the originals on its glass flatbed manually, hardly you would receive your fair share of praise when you sent the scans to your daughter.

The scanner doesn't care what you put into it - as long as it fits inside. It does its best, but the result is not up to the expectations. However, had you first taken the vinyl records to an experienced musician who would write them down as musical score, scanning those sheets would result in real delight of your child.

In C++, different types may differ to an extent that a printed sheet of paper differs from a CD. A C++ function expecting to receive an array of `short`s will process any sequence of bytes/bits as an array of `short`s. It doesn't care that the memory area is actually filled with values of a different type, having a completely different representation, just like the scanner didn't care about the contents of the stack on the ADF. Assuming that a function will internally convert each element of the array from `double` to `short`, is the same as believing that a photocopier includes a gramophone and a musician that will automatically transcribe vinyl recordings to sheet form. Note that the latter is a possible design for a real-world photocopier, and some other programming languages work like that. But not existing implementations of<sup>1</sup> C++.

---

<sup>1</sup> In theory, a standard compliant implementation of C/C++ is possible that would interpret all provisions of UB in the language in favor of the opposite answer to your question, rather than in favor of best performance. But that would make little sense for a language like C/C++.